# Sort-Object not sorting as expected

Tags: sorting, powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have a very large CSV (pipe delimited) with four columns (ID, NAME, Value, Date (yyyy-MM-dd))

I am trying to delete all of the rows with a date that doesn't equal the most recent date. To do this I need to know what the most recent date in the file is.

To test the sorting I decided to use the value column (int). The script below is not ordering the file at all on any of the columns and I cannot see why (have tried with and without casting the column to an int.

```
Set-Location '<File_Path>'

$file = 'file1.txt'

Import-Csv $file -Delimiter '|' |
  Sort-Object @{e= { "Value" -as [int] }} -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 10
```

Once I have the sorting working, I can select the first value and work with that to remove rows which don't match. Below is a sample set:

```
"ID"|"NAME"|"Value"|"Date"
"ID000001"|"ID000001"|560000|2008-06-30
"ID000002"|"ID000002"|1490|2013-12-31
"ID000003"|"ID000003"|112038|2013-09-30
"ID000004"|"ID000004"|201103|2013-12-31
"ID000005"|"ID000005"|78205|2014-01-31
"ID000006"|"ID000006"|78205|2014-02-28
"ID000007"|"ID000007"|78205|2014-03-31
"ID000008"|"ID000008"|183979|2014-04-30
"ID000009"|"ID000009"|311380|2014-08-29
"ID000010"|"ID000010"|311380|2014-09-30
"ID000011"|"ID000011"|232693|2014-10-31
"ID000012"|"ID000012"|232693|2014-11-28
"ID000013"|"ID000013"|343243|2014-12-31
"ID000014"|"ID000014"|253822|2015-01-30
"ID000015"|"ID000015"|377489|2015-02-27
"ID000016"|"ID000016"|214111|2015-03-31
"ID000017"|"ID000017"|5690|2009-06-30
"ID000018"|"ID000018"|5690|2009-12-31
"ID000019"|"ID000019"|5690|2010-06-30
"ID000020"|"ID000020"|5000|2010-10-31
"ID000021"|"ID000021"|5000|2010-11-30
"ID000022"|"ID000022"|5000|2010-12-31
"ID000023"|"ID000023"|5000|2011-01-31
"ID000024"|"ID000024"|5000|2011-02-28
"ID000025"|"ID000025"|5000|2011-05-31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `"Value" -as [int]` always returns `$null`.

I believe you want

```
@{e = { $_.Value -as [int] }}
```

instead

If you are using PowerShell 2.0, the `-as` operator doesn't exist, and you'll have to use an explicit cast instead:

```
@{e = { [int]$_.Value }}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, I found the solution and just posted; But your suggestion is correct. Will mark this post as the answer as technically it was posted first

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the e= in Sort-object. I needed to append $_. to the name of the column:

```
Set-Location '<File_Path>'

$file = 'file1.txt'

Import-Csv $file -Delimiter '|' | Sort-Object @{e= { $_."Value" -as [int] }} -Descending | Select-Object -First 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the imported CSV by date, sort the groups by name (i.e. date), then select and expand the last group:

```
Import-Csv $file -Delimiter '|' |
  Group-Object Date |
  Sort-Object Name |
  Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand Group
```

If every record in your file has a different date you can skip the grouping and simply sort by date and select the last record:

```
Import-Csv $file -Delimiter '|' |
  Sort-Object Date |
  Select-Object -Last 1
```